# Negative range for binary cross entropy loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

So based on the website:

https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-binary-cross-entropy-log-loss-a-visual-explanation-a3ac6025181a

The binary cross entropy loss is defined as:

[image]

Which is applicable for **output range {0,1}**. However, what if i **scale** the output to be now **{-1,1}** instead? How would the new cross entropy loss be derived?

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do, is forcing your labels (${-1,1}$) to be ${0,1}$ using this simple linear transformation:

\begin{equation*}\hat{y} = (y + 1) / 2\end{equation*}

This way, -1 maps to 0, and 1 maps to 1.

For practical purposes, you can either change the outputs and labels of your model directly (before applying the original BCE), or slightly change to BCE loss function according to the linear transformation:

\begin{equation}H_p(q) = -\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(y_i+1)}{2} \log\left(p\left(y_i\right)\right) + (1-\frac{(y_i+1)}{2})\log\left(1-p\left(y_i\right)\right)\end{equation}

Notice that I changed only the coefficients, assuming that the probability function $p$ only returns meaningful values for ${-1,1}$

NOTE: obviously, all of this is relevant only for the **binary** cross entropy case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that u can do is instead (1-yi) one can use (-1-yi) in cross-entropy formula.

Hp(q)=−1/N ∑i=1N(yi)log(p(yi))+(-1-yi)log(1−p(yi)).